# Misalignment of TikZ nodes when using positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

When positioning several nodes containing TikZ pictures themselves relative to each other (using the `positioning` TikZ library), it seems like the nodes in the contained pictures become slightly misaligned:

[image: Node misalignment]

This picture results from the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt]

\newcommand{\makeTikzTree}[1]{%
    \FPeval{\result}{#1/2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.4]
        \draw (0, 0) -- (0, -1) node[vertex]{};
        \ifodd#1
            \draw (0, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
            \foreach \x in {1, ..., \result} {
                \draw (-\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
                \draw (\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
            }
        \else
            \foreach \x in {0.5, ..., \result} {
                \draw (-\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
                \draw (\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
            }
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (tree1) {\makeTikzTree{5}};
        \node [right=of tree1] (tree2) {\makeTikzTree{4}};
        \node [right=of tree2] (tree3) {\makeTikzTree{7}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Notice how the alignment on the first tree is fine. What's going on here? How come this works just fine if specifying absolute positions for the nodes, but not with relative positioning?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, you are nesting `tikzpicture`s, which should be avoided, and which is the reason for the misalignment. Also `\tikzstyle` is deprecated (but is not the reason for the problems).

Answer (score 4):

Your code unfortunately nests `tikzpicture`s. This is to be avoided because the values of the pgf keys of the ambient picture get inherited. You also do not need to do that, Ti*k*Z has `pic`s for that purpose. Even then you need to make sure that the `vertex` does not inherit the anchor from the positioning. `right` implies that the anchor is `west`, which explains that all the vertices get connected at their left. You can avoid this by adding `anchor=center` to the options of `vertex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum
    size=2pt,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center},
        pics/little tree/.style={code={
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmax}{#1/2}
         \draw (0, 0) -- (0, -1) node[vertex]{};
        \ifodd#1
            \draw (0, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
            \foreach \x in {1, ..., \xmax} {
                \draw (-\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
                \draw (\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
            }
        \else
            \foreach \x in {0.5, ..., \xmax} {
                \draw (-\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
                \draw (\x, 1) node[vertex]{} -- (0, 0);
            }
        \fi}}]
        \node[matrix] (tree1) {\pic[scale=0.4]{little tree=5};\\};
        \node[matrix,right=of tree1] (tree2) {\pic[scale=0.4]{little tree=4};\\};
        \node[matrix,right=of tree2] (tree3) {\pic[scale=0.4]{little tree=7};\\};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of  \\ in the `node`s?

Comment: @Sigur This is a trick: use a `matrix` as a wrapper of the `pic` such that `positioning` can be used fro relative positioning. The OP seems to want to use `positioning` for nodes that contain `pic`s, and this is one possible way to position `pic`s like nodes, perhaps currently the only way.

Answer (score 2):

As Schrödinger's cat has done, I would implement your trees as a `pic`. You can simplify your code as:

```
\tikzset{
  vertex/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt},
  pics/tree/.style = {
      code = {
      \begin{scope}[scale=0.4, thick]
        \node[vertex] (0) at (0,0){};
        \draw(0)--(0,1);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {
          \node[vertex] (n\x) at (\x-#1/2-1/2,2){};
          \draw(0,1)--(n\x);
        }
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
```

In particular, note that you do not need `\FPeval` or to use `\ifodd`. Also, `\tikzstyle` has been depreciated in favour of `\tikzset`.

With this in place, my understanding of the positioning library from examples is that the following code should work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic (tree1) at (0,0){tree=5};
  \pic[right=of tree1] (tree2) {tree=4};
  \pic[right=of tree2] (tree3) {tree=7};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but for reasons that I do not understand this gives an error. 
Rather than using the `positioning library` I prefer to plant the trees manually to give:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use Schrödinger's cat's nice trick:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix] (tree1) {\pic{tree=5};\\};
  \node[matrix,right=of tree1] (tree2) {\pic{tree=4};\\};
  \node[matrix,right=of tree2] (tree3) {\pic{tree=7};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  vertex/.style={circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt},
  pics/tree/.style = {
      code = {
      \begin{scope}[scale=0.4, thick]
        \node[vertex] (0) at (0,0){};
        \draw(0)--(0,1);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {
          \node[vertex] (n\x) at (\x-#1/2-1/2,2){};
          \draw(0,1)--(n\x);
        }
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic at (0,0){tree=5};
        \pic at (2,0){tree=4};
        \pic at (4.5,0){tree=7};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

  % Schrödinger's cat's nice trick
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[matrix] (tree1) {\pic{tree=5};\\};
    \node[matrix,right=of tree1] (tree2) {\pic{tree=4};\\};
    \node[matrix,right=of tree2] (tree3) {\pic{tree=7};\\};
  \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```